# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'copy'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to copy text to clipboard using [JQUERY CLIPBOARD COPY](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/copy)

jQuery:

```
  $("#sample").copy();
```

Html:

```
<div id="sample">Say hello</div>
```

While trying to run this code, am getting the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'copy'

Comment: Is plugin loaded at time you are trying to use it?

Comment: Match your included files with this post: https://code.google.com/p/sinchosaur/source/browse/branches/0.1.2/Site/Content/js/jquery.copy.js?r=24

Comment: @roasted - Yes, am using the latest jquery plugin (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js). its getting loaded !

Comment: But copy() method is not part of jquery, it is part of the plugin you linked. BTW, i don't see any link to download it

Answer (score 0):

You need to have plugin for this, there is no default method for copy. So download the plugin and use

Comment: Thanks for your response ! Can you share me the plugin link for copy() method !

Answer (score 0):

Probably the plugin is not loaded yet.
Can you try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sample").copy();
});
```